# What is the difference between A321neo and A321neo LR?

Tags: airbus-a320, airbus, airbus-neo

According to the illustration on this [Airbus webpage about the A321Neo XLR](https://aircraft.airbus.com/en/aircraft/a320/a321xlr), the A321Neo has 3500 NM range and A321Neo LR has 4000 NM range which is in conflict with this [Airbus website about the A320Neo](https://aircraft.airbus.com/en/aircraft/a320/a320neo), the A320Neo has 3400 NM range, and in this [Airbus website about the A321Neo](https://aircraft.airbus.com/en/aircraft/a320/a321neo#routes), they claim the A321Neo to have a 4000 NM range.

I wanted to know whether there is a difference between A321Neo and A321Neo LR or are they referring to the A321Neo as A321Neo LR?

Comment: The website about the A320 has a different figure than the A321 because they are different airplanes.

Answer (score 4):

The Airbus website is not incorrect, but there is a slight inconsistency between how the A321 LR is referred to. On one page it is marketed as a special aircraft, on the other it is implied that it is just one of the A321NEO varieties.

Note that the A320 page linked in your question is unrelated; it is a different aircraft.

The A321NEO and the A321LR are very similar aircraft.

In the [certification data sheet](https://www.easa.europa.eu/downloads/16507/en), the A321NEO is designated as A321-2xxN (xx either 51, 52, 53 , 71 or 72, indicating engine model). These aircraft are build with either 3, 4 or 5 tanks. The basic aircraft has 3 tanks; two wing tanks and a centre tank. Optionally, one or two Additional Centre Tanks (ACT) can be installed.

A variety of the A321NEO is approved as A321-2xxNX (same xx numbers). This version can have an increased maximum ramp weight and maximum take-off weight (up to 97 metric tonnes) and offers up to three ACTs. The option with three ACTs is marketed as the A321 Long Range. In the certification, the A321LR is a variety (modification) of the A321NEO.